# Get Callable value using CompletableFuture or Future Object

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, java-threads

Future.get() method is a blocking method, I just want my main method to not bother for f.get() and continue with its execution.

How to get the callable returned value from Future or CompletableFuture without compromising with main thread execution and without using any loop for constantly checking using isDone()

````
        FutureTask<String> result = (FutureTask<String>) es.submit(new Helloo());
//      CompletableFuture<String> r =  CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(()a -> new Hello(), es);
        Future<String> r = es.submit(new Hello());
        es.execute(()->{System.out.println("hello");});
                System.out.println("Main");

                System.out.println("Main");
                System.out.println("Main");
                System.out.println("Main");
                System.out.println(r.get());

                System.out.println("Main");
                System.out.println("Main");```
````

Comment: What do you mean by "retrieve callable returned value"? Do you mean get the value?

Comment: @ThisIsNoZaku .. Yes get the returned value

Answer (score 0):

If you want to supply (calculate/generate/retrieve/etc.) some value then do something with that value asynchronously, you can create a `CompletableFuture` via a method such as [CompletableFuture.supplyAsync](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#supplyAsync-java.util.function.Supplier-). This will return an instance of `CompletableFuture`.

With that instance, you can call the method `thenAccept`, which will call the given `Consumer` method, with the value supplied by the previous step as the argument.

So something kind of like this:

```
CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(aMethodThatWillReturnAString, yourExecutor).thenAccept((string theString) -> {
    System.out.println(theString);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean the callback of the CompletableStage? 
Something like 
 CompletableFuture r =  CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(()a -> new Hello()).thenAccept(s -> s + World());

Comment: ok! so I just want to submit a callable task which will return a value; I just don't main want to wait for future.get method